# How to get rid of the "files in use" dialog during uninstall?

Tags: wix

I'm very new to WIX and am using the minimal GUI to install and uninstall a dll. This dll gets registered as a service in a custom install script that I am calling upon install.

Upon uninstall, I stop and unregister the service in a custom script.

My problem is, before the custom uninstall script is called, I get the files in use dialog box as the dll is being used by the service. I want to avoid this, as I know I will be stopping the service in the custom uninstall action.

Any easy solutions to this problem ?

Thanks!
Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Custom Action to stop the service?  If so I'd make sure that your custom action is run before the removal of your file

i.e.

```
<CustomAction Id="StopService" Directory="DirMyService" ExeCommand="NET STOP ServiceName" />
<CustomAction Id="StartService" Directory="DirMyService" ExeCommand="NET START ServiceName" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="StopService" After="InstallInitialize">Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="StartService" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Haven't tested this, so you may need to stick in the windir before the net stop etc, and those might be the wrong places to put it in to stop/start the scripts.  But might give you an idea of how to solve your problem.